# MySql Query - optimization with varchars, indexs, taking over an hour to run

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization

So I need to run a query that I do not know the UUID - but need to find it... so I am using the street num, street name, and a company UUID to find it

I have a few million records, and this took query is taking around an HOUR!!

any advice to speed it up?

```
gisPoints
UUID  Indexed Unique    varchar(36)
street_num  int(11)
street_name varchar(128)

geoPoint_temp
UUID  Indexed Unique    varchar(36)
street_num  int(11)
street_name varchar(128)
gcomUUID Indexed    varchar(36)


update geoPoint_temp as temp JOIN gisPoints as `prod` on prod.gcomUUID=temp.gcomUUIDand prod.street_num=temp.street_num and prod.street_name REGEXP(temp.street_name)
        set temp.UUID=prod.UUID,temp.customerUUID=prod.customerUUID     WHERE temp.`uploadstate` = '1'";
```

Comment: what is happening inside your query? I see you are preforming an update, but on what table? Are you preforming a JOIN operation to create a "temporary table" and then updating that temporary table? Or did you want to update a table that already existed?

Comment: I am inserting the UUID from gisPoints into the geoPoint_temp table

Comment: I understand that, however when you preform a `JOIN` action, you are creating a temporary table. So if I have for instance `SELECT a.ID, b.DATE FROM a JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID`, I will be creating a table that is neither `a` nor `b`. So your code currently is doing `UPDATE (your join code) SET ...`, where your join code is creating a temporary table. Do you agree with me the table you are updating is temporary?

Comment: alright... makes sense, I am updating the geoPoint_temp though, not the temp table

Comment: Is your table being updated at all? did it update after the hour passed?

Comment: i did it with a smaller set, and it did update succesfully, not running it with the big one and its still running :/

Comment: My personal opinion is that the `JOIN` operation is literally processing millions of combinations, resulting in a HUGE temporary table, which is probably still being created given how big it might be. There might very well be a better way of writing the query.

Comment: I wrote an answer where the process of finding the UUID should be quite fast, and then you can use the UUID to update the file. That was at least what I understood you were looking for. If I misunderstood something, let me know.

Comment: How much RAM?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';` -- I ask these because of the performance evils of UUIDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This runs in 1.5 seconds opposed to the hours it was taking before
Much help to @Webeng for pointing us in the right direction!

```
$custquery="UPDATE geoPoint_temp as temp
        join
        (
                        select prod.name, prod.street_num, prod.street_name, prod.UUID,prod.customerUUID, prod.gcomUUID 
                        FROM gisPoints as `prod`
                        JOIN
                        (
                                        select t1.gcomUUID , t1.street_num, t1.street_name
                                        FROM geoPoint_temp as t1
                        ) as sub1 on prod.gcomUUID =sub1.gcomUUID  and prod.street_num=sub1.street_num
        ) as sub2 on sub2.gcomUUID =temp.gcomUUID 
        and sub2.street_num=temp.street_num
        AND sub2.street_name LIKE (CONCAT('%',temp.street_name,'%'))
        set temp.customerUUID = sub2.customerUUID, temp.UUID=sub2.UUID";
        $custre=mysql_query($custquery);
        if (!$custre) {    echo 'Could not run custre query: ' . mysql_error();    exit;    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following values (in PHP):

```
$street_num  = ...;//something
$street_name = ...;//something
$gcomUUID = ...;//something
```

If you run the following sql code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM geoPoint_temp WHERE gcomUUID = $gcomUUID) 
    WHERE street_name = $street_name)
WHERE street_num = $street_num;"
```

You should obtain a list of rows (0 or more) from geoPoint_temp that have matching values, and it should be relatively fast even in a big table.

After obtaining those rows, you can check if the row count is greater than zero, and if so update the rows. If your using MySQL (PDO), you could do something similar to the following:

```
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($count>0)
{
  $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
  foreach ($rows as $row)
  {
    $sql = "UPDATE geoPoint_temp SET ... WHERE UUID = ".$row['UUID'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
  }
}
```

Let me know if that helped.

**EDITED:**

Try the following as well and let me know if it works:

```
$sql = "
UPDATE geoPoint_temp SET ... WHERE UUID IN 
    (SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT * FROM geoPoint_temp WHERE gcomUUID = $gcomUUID) 
        WHERE street_name = $street_name)
    WHERE street_num = $street_num);"
```

And replace `...` with the values you want updated.

Comment: I would have to have an additional query, then do a while loop to iterate through the geoPoint_temp to fill out the street_num,street_name,gcomUUID.  What I was trying to do is let mysql do the heavy lifting

Comment: Im pretty sure sql could do all of it, what I personally am not sure of is how to write the conditional for the `UPDATE` query. If I modify the first `$sql` statement in my answer to start with `$sql = "SELECT ID FROM ...` and keep all the rest the same, I would literally have a column of the IDs that need to be updated, however when updating, what I dont know is how to write the where conditional with a column: `UPDATE geoPoint_temp SET ... WHERE ???`. I know we already have a column with the ID's that need to be compared, but will sql allow you to compare `WHERE UUID = [column obtained]`?

Comment: @morty346 cool, let me know how you did it if it works, I am interested in knowing as well hahah

Comment: @morty346 I have updated my answer with an option that should work, let me know if it does.

Comment: Added mine below - if you want to update yours to reflect changes, I'd be happy to select yours as the answer - since you got us in right direction - Thanks again!